# R function to join to summaries

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to merge these two into the example as above. How do I go about this? I created these using this kind of code:

```
kids1 <- segmentdata %>%
  summarise("Segment"="Aggregated",
            "Max"=max(kids),
            "mean"=mean(kids),
            "Min"=min(kids),
            "Std.dev"=sd(kids),
            "Variance"=var(kids))
```

```
          Aggregate  Suburb Mix
ownHome      29%        15%         
isSub        23%        13%     
isMale       26%        21%
```

```
Percentage
<chr>
ownHome 15%         
isSub   13%         
isMale  21%
```

```
Percentage
<chr>
ownHome 29%         
isSub   23%         
isMale  26%
```

Sorry for bad post, new to coding and stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the r-base function cbind for that you will need it to be dataframes and have the same row names.
Sample data:

```
b=data.frame("percentage"=c(31,4,7), row.names = c("first","second","third"))
a=data.frame("percentage"=c(12,8,2), row.names = c("first","second","third"))
```

**cbind()** use:

```
result = cbind(a,b)
```

**result**

| names | percentage | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | 12% | 31% |
| second | 8% | 4% |
| third | 2% | 7% |

Comment: I think the row names and numbers are combined into one single row. I don't think you can only use `cbind`. He also wanted to change the column names